# Неявное преобразование в C++

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Добрый вечер. У меня снова вопрос по шаблонному классу. 
У меня есть следующий код:

```
template <class T>
class List {
    static const int defaultCapacity = 20;
    static const int defaultSize = 0;

    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int size;
    T* list;

public:
    List() : capacity(defaultCapacity), size(defaultSize) //, list = new T[size] 
    {
        list = new T[capacity];
    }

    ~List()
    {
        delete[] list;
    }

    const T& operator[] (unsigned int i) const
    {
        return list[i];
    }

    void Add(const T& item)
    {
        if(size < capacity)
            list[size++] = item;
        else 
        {
            auto tmp = list;
            delete[] list;
            list = new T[capacity *= 2];
            memcpy(list, tmp, sizeof(tmp) * sizeof(T));
            size++;
        }
    }

    void Remove(unsigned int i)
    {
        if (i > size)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid index");

        if(size > i)
            memcpy(&list[i], &list[i + 1], sizeof(T) * size - i); 
        list[--size] = 0;
    }

    void Insert(unsigned int i, const T& item)
    {
        unsigned int tempSize = size - i + 1;
        T* tmp = new T[tempSize];
        memcpy(&tmp, &list[i], sizeof(T) * tempSize);

        if(++size >= capacity)
        {
            capacity *= 2;
            delete[] list;
            list = new T[capacity];
        }

        list[i] = item;
        memcpy(&list[i + 1], tmp, tempSize); 
        delete[] tmp;
    }

    unsigned int getSize() const
    {
        return size;
    }
 };

//...

int main()
{

    auto intList = new List<int>();
    intList->Add(3);

    int i =  intList[0]; // ошибка  возникает тут

    //...       
    delete intList;
    return 0;
}
```

Возникает следующая ошибка: 
error C2440: инициализация: невозможно преобразовать "List<T>" в "int"
Но разве здесь нужно преобразование - ведь operator[] возвращает T&, то есть ссылку на int?

Comment: Полностью код класса List покажите.

Comment: Как минимум одну ошибку вижу. У вас list[i] возвращает константную ссылку, а тип результата -- неконстантная ссылка. Но компилятор бы тогда другую ошибку выдавал.

Comment: весь код показал, правда там большая часть не имеет отношения к вопросу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Объявление `auto` в вашем случае равносильно `List<int>*`, то есть объявляет тип "указатель на объект `List<int>`".
- Далее, `intList[0]` равносильно `*(intList + 0)`, то есть `*intList`, то есть разыменованному указателю на `List<int>`.
- Поскольку вы пытаетесь присвоить результат разыменования указателя переменной типа `int`, то возникает ошибка компиляции, поскольку такое преобразование недопустимо в пределах вашей единицы трансляции.
- Исправить это вы можете путем аллокации `intList` на `stack'e` или замены `intList[0]` на `(*intList)[0]`.

Comment: спасибо) что-то я ступил немного)